# treating string with numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My code:

```js
test = '1.111,111'
test2 = parseFloat(test)
test3 = test.replace(/,/g, '.')
console.log(test2)//1.111
console.log(parseFloat(test3))//1.111
```

I need the whole number returned as a string in the "test" variable to be returned.

I want the return of: 1.111,111 in number format.

How can I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `test3 = test.replace(/,/g, '')`? When do you see commas in decimal anyways?

Comment: @StackSlave In many locales.

Answer (score 0):

I'll break this into steps for you to understand better:

```
test = '1.111,111';
test2 = test.split('.').join(''));
test3 = test2.replace(',', '.');
test4 = parseFloat(test3);
```

You can do this in one line:

```
test = parseFloat(test.split('.').join('').replace(',', '.'));
```